# How to determine patterns in a string and count their occurrences

Tags: string, pattern-matching, computer-science, counting

I'm trying to find patterns in a string and count the number of times that each pattern occurs.

I've come up with a solution that works but I suspect that I'm missing some key Computer Science knowledge that can help me solve this in a better way.

```
<?php
/**
 * 1. Find patterns in a string.
 * 2. Count the number of times that each pattern occurs.
 * 
 * @author Kiril Reznik <aternus>
 */
$string = 'abcdabcdab';
```

https://ideone.com/y0NvDb

Since I'm learning this by myself, ideally I'm looking for someone to review the code, point me towards the right materials and explain the theory - without providing a direct solution.

Comment: Why don't you post the code in the question? We're just going to end up with a broken link at some point in the future.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I'm not sure how your suggestion is relevant to the solution. Ideone links won't be broken unless they are deleted by the author, which I'm not planning to do.